# How to add class to any "div" or "li" or "a" with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I want yo add class to any div or li wihout editing the div. Actually i found a plugin named animate it in wordpress and i need to add "animate it class" to animate any content. So i want to animate my products in woocommerce. But the problem is, i cant edit the html. So  simply my question is that how can i add a class to a div by javascript if i know it's id or class.

How to do that in the example given below.
`<div id="product-1" class="my-product-1">this is product 1</div>`

Comment: The ***slightest*** bit of research would point you to `document.getElementById` and `className`/`classList`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('div, li').addClass('newClass');
});
```

You can replace 'div, li' by putting there any class or id you want i.e:

```
$('.class').addClass('newClass');
```

or

```
$('#id').addClass('newClass');
```

More info:
https://api.jquery.com/addclass/

Comment: Try to put it on bottom of your site before the end of <body></body> tag. Remember to use <script type="text/javascript>/js code here/</script> tagg.

Comment: this will be as good as hard coding it to `DOM`, you are probably looking for an `event` viz. `click` or `hover` of something

Comment: What is DOM ? I Don don't know any thing about javascript. And i am using wordpress. So can you tell me where should i place thr code.

Answer (score 0):

Add a space plus the name of your new class to the `className` property of the element. First, put an `id` on the element so you can easily get a reference.

```
<div id="div1" class="someclass">
    <img ... id="image1" name="image1" />
</div>
```

Then

```
var d = document.getElementById("div1");
d.className += " otherclass";
```

reference from https://stackoverflow.com/posts/507157/edit

See also [element.className on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className).

Answer (score 0):

Pure javascript solution, make sure to run it when the DOM is loaded.

```js
var items = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  items[i].className += "item";
}

console.log(items);
```

```html
<a>1</a>
<a>2</a>
<a>3</a>
<a>4</a>
```

Comment: What is DOM ? I Don don't know any thing about javascript. And i am using wordpress. So can you tell me where should i place thr code.

Answer (score 0):

You Can use DOM Element

```
document.getElementsByID("#id").setAttribute("class", "democlass");
```